# Partitioned step remains in started state when deployed on a 2 node cluster

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch

I have a QueueChannel which is an output channel for my aggregator. The code works just fine on a single node cluster. The moment, I deploy it on 2 node cluster, the partitionStep is not completed and remains in STARTED state forever. Looking at PartitionStep it seems it waiting in the receive method and never marks the step COMPLETED. Below is the configuration that I am using.

```
<bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
        <property name="environment">
            <props>
                <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">${oag_wl_nodes_url}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate" />
        <property name="jndiName" value="jmsConnectionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <int:channel id="requestsChannel" />

    <bean id="reqQueue" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean"
        lazy-init="true" scope="prototype">
        <property name="jndiTemplate">
            <ref bean="jndiTemplate" />
        </property>
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>masterRequestQueue</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter
        connection-factory="connectionFactory" channel="requestsChannel" destination="reqQueue" />

    <int:channel id="replyChannel" />

    <bean id="replyQueue" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean"
        lazy-init="true" scope="prototype">
        <property name="jndiTemplate">
            <ref bean="jndiTemplate" />
        </property>
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>masterReplyQueue</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter connection-factory="connectionFactory" destination="replyQueue" 
            channel="replyChannel" acknowledge="transacted" />

    <int:channel id="aggregatedReplyChannel">
        <int:queue />
    </int:channel>

    <int:aggregator ref="partitionHandler" 
            input-channel="replyChannel" output-channel="aggregatedReplyChannel" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a common reply queue `replyQueue`; that won't work because the two instances are competing for the replies and the reply might be consumed by the non-master node.

You need a separate reply destination for each.

That said, I don't see you setting up the replyTo at all on the outbound message, so I assume your replyTo is hard-coded on the consumer side..

You might find it easier to use an outbound gateway instead of a pair of channel adapters; the gateway will create a temporary reply queue (by default) for each request.

Comment: Hi Gary, Thanks for the reply. Since we are using common reply queue. Can the aggregator read from that reply queue and put the messages in queue channel. The aggregator config above says that the input channel is replychannel and the output channel is the aggregatedReplyChannel which is a queue channel. Can't we get away with our message driven channel adapter so that it doesn't consume anything from replyqueue and the aggregator consumes the messages from the reply queue on master node and puts them in the output channel I.e. aggregatedReplyChannel.

Comment: Some background here..., the job in our case is invoked from an endpoint which would be triggered from one node that can be treated as master node. We are assuming that the master config should be loaded from this node only. Is our assumption correct? Will the master config be triggered from other node as well? Our slave config is a separate config file that is loaded using the spring listener at the server startup so that both cluster nodes will listen to our request queue

Comment: I said that because it is common to have all nodes as peers and one is selected at runtime to launch the job. In that case, you need a dedicated reply channel for each. If you only have one master and thus one consumer on the reply queue, it shouldn't be a problem. The channel types don't matter. I suggest you turn on DEBUG logging and follow the messages on both the master and slave(s).

Comment: Thanks again. One more thing. Does the SI framework configuration has a provision to make aggregators active only on master node from the configuration. Currently we are using spring app context to load the master config from within the endpoint. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: You can set `auto-startup="false"` on the message-driven channel adapter, and only start it on the master node.

Comment: Yes we can do that but the nodes are not designated as master or slave. We want that the node that is serving the endpoint must be designated as master at run time. Declaring auto-startup to false will never start  the consumer on any of the nodes. I read that control bus should be used to start the channel adapter. But am not sure how it works. Reuest you to please help us  configure it. Thanks Anuj

Comment: You can either use the control bus, or simply `@Autowire` the `JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint` and start/stop it directly.

Comment: This works but the challenge is how to ensure that the master and consumer are always on the same node. Consider if two instances of the job are launched in parallel and there could be chances of both being run on same node or different nodes. How shall we ensure that the consumer will consume only the messages that pertain to the job launched from the node it is active on?

Comment: Several options, some if which I have already mentioned: 1) Switch to gateways, 2) use a unique reply queue for each node and set the `jms_replyTo` header on outbound messages, and use a `destination-expression` on the slaves to send the replies there, 3) Use a single reply queue, but set some arbitrary header `fooHeader=node23` and use a `selector="fooHeader=node23"` on the message-driven adapter to select only messages that originated at this node.

Comment: 3rd one is what we went with. We had overridden MessageChannelPartitionHandler to add nodename in the header while creating the message. On the messagedriven channel adapter we added the selector as selector="nodename=nodeA". Although, the header is added in the message but the selector didn't work. The Partitioned step didn't complete. I further read that message selector is used by message filter. This is as per SI framework and JMS spec. Are we missing something? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't know; if you can put together a simple test case that reproduces your issue, I can take a look.

Comment: It was my mistake assigned selector="nodename = 'nodeA'". Single quotes were missing so selector was not working. Still there is an issue and it seems wierd. Receive method returns the message before completing slave step which is a flow step and marks the partitionstep as complete. We expected that partitionstep would complete in the last after the slave step is completed. This behavior works without selector on single node but fails on the cluster. PL let me know in case further info is required.

Comment: Sorry; I have no ideas; looking at DEBUG logs on master and slave should help.